# What is the name of this component like image below

Tags: angular

I am creating a component in angular 4 that dislays text with random position on the screen but i don't know. Please help me!
[image]

Comment: There is no image visible, something must have gone wrong in your question. Try to check which CSS framework they use, then you will easy find the component.

Comment: I correct your question for see the image. You are looking for "tag cloud"

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea in creating a tag cloud is to use **nth-of-type** in CSS and apply it on your selected **li** elements. Use random expressions like (2n + 3), (3n), .. etc

eg:

```
.cloud li:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
.cloud li:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

For a faster approach you can use plugins which are readily available. You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module) one for Angular apps